# Character to Integer

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wanting to know if there is a better way of finding the decimal value of each character in a string than through this solution I've produced in Excel VBA.

```
'Converting Variables
Dim SingleVal As String '<------ Character
Dim DecimalVal As Integer   '<-- Character's Base 10 value

For k1 = 1 To Len(InputVal)

    'Finding each Character
    SingleVal = Mid(InputVal, k1, 1)
    For DecimalVal = 1 To 255
        If SingleVal = Chr(DecimalVal) Then GoTo MatchFound
    Next DecimalVal

    'Did not find match
    GoTo Error1

    'Character Match Found
MatchFound:
    [Additional Code]
Next k1
```

Comment: Chr$ will be more efficient but what is the overall purpose of this? And why use a GotTo?

Comment: I think that you are looking for `Asc()`, which is the inverse to `Chr()`.

Comment: @QHarr The `GoTo` is because some foreign languages have characters that I don't have in Excel. The overall purpose is to learn more about programming, so I chose to learn the basics of how to encrypt and decrypt information.

Comment: Instead of `GoTo Error1` consider `Exit Function` (assuming that's a function), or `Err.Raise` to raise a proper error and handle it as such. `GoTo` is not something you need, 99.9999% of the time.

Comment: `GoTo MatchFound` can be replaced with a Boolean local variable. `If SingleVal = Chr$(DecimalVal) Then` `isFound = True`  `Exit For` `End If`. And then `If isFound Then` {rest of code} `Else` {no match was found}... which also gets rid of `GoTo Error1`.

Comment: I noticed someone (cannot recall where) placing a `GoTo` for error handling at the end of a procedure and thought it was a good way of organizing error messages for a procedure. So I started applying the method.

Comment: `GoTo` is a one-way road to spaghetticode town. Don't mistake it for `On Error GoTo`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ASC()` to get the ASCII value of a character.  Vba has no Char type so calling `Chr()` after `Mid()` would be unnecessary.

```
'Converting Variables
Dim SingleVal As String '<------ Character
Dim DecimalVal As Integer

For k1 = 1 To Len(InputVal)

    'Finding each Character
    SingleVal = Mid(InputVal, k1, 1)
    DecimalVal = Asc(SingleVal)

    [Additional Code]
Next k1
```